# covariance and correlation of x and y

Tags: covariance

Given that the independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ have variance $36$ and $16$
respectively. Find
(i)  $Var(X + Y)$
(ii) $Var(X – Y)$
(iii) the correlation coefficient between $(X + Y)$ and $(X – Y)$
 I found the answers for the first $2$ parts which is basically the addition of the variances and that is $52$.
But for the third part  $\text{correlation}= Cov(x+y,x-y)/(stdx.stdy)$
how do i find $Cov(x+y,x-y)$ because $cov(x,y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$. how do i find the expectations as they are not given. Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, Please, have a look at the link down for some hints on writing math-equations. It is usually expected that you include some of your own attempts to solve the problem. Do you know that "independent" implies zero covariance? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

The covariance of two independent r.v is equal to zero, hence $\mbox{cov}[X,Y] = 0$. To find the answer to your question use:
$$\mbox{cov}[X+Y,X-Y] = \mbox{cov}[X,X]+\mbox{cov}[Y,X]-\mbox{cov}[X,Y]-\mbox{cov}[Y,Y].$$